# Introductory Calculus: Finding Critical Point using basic methods

Tags: calculus, derivatives

Find Critical Points of: 
$$s(t)={t^3\over 3}-6t^2+50t$$
Here is my working out for finding the critical point:
$s'(t)=3t^2-6t+50$

$3t^2-6t+50=0$
...
$-{3t^2\over 6}+t={50\over 6}$

As stated by many people I did compute the derivative wrong, here is the correct first derivative:
$$s'(t)=t^2-12t+50$$

**My Original Question Information:**

> I'm not sure if the first derivative can be factorized nicely to visually see the critical point(s). So I tried to solve but I am stuck as shown above.
>
> Using calculus at a beginners level, how can I find the critical points if they exist?

**Question from the Lecture:**
Use differential calculus to find the value of t when the velocity is a **minimum**. Also calculate how far the object is from the origin at that time.

Note: This is my first post so I apologize if the formatting isn't great.

**EDIT: Fixed the first derivative and added the question from the lecture.**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately you have differentiated incorrectly:
$$s(t)={t^3\over3}-6t^2+50t$$ differentiates, term by term, to $${ds\over dt}=t^2-12t+50$$ which unfortunately has no real roots because the discriminant is negative ($12^2-4\times1\times50 <0$), so the gradient is never 0 and there are no critical points

https://www.desmos.com/calculator/f5ra4vftg

Answer (score 1):

You computed the derivative wrong;

$s(t)={t^3\over 3}-6t^2+50t$ $\Rightarrow$ $s'(t)= t^2-12t+50$.

And here, because the discriminant is less than zero function has no critical points.

Answer (score 0):

The critical points are the solutions to the quadratic equation you gave. You can solve quadratic equations by using the quadratic formula.

Comment: I have to use calculus to solve the problem, I'll edit my post to make that more clear.

Comment: You have used calculus when you differentiated to get the quadratic.

Comment: Ok thanks for clearing that up, I wasn't sure to what extent "Only using Calculus" covered. So in this case using the Quadratic Formula would be the only option without going into advanced techniques?

Comment: it is the only option there are no advanced techniques

Comment: Thanks, if I had enough rep to vote you up I would :(

Comment: I think you can select this as the answer to the question

Answer (score 0):

You seem to have some mistakes in $s'(t)$:

$$
s'(t) =t^2-12t+50
$$

Now, to find the zeroes of $s'$, use the quadratic formula, and analyze the nature of the critical points with a table :)